# c++ on enum class comparision

Tags: c++, char

```
enum class Status: char {
    test1 = '1',
    test2 = '1'
};

int main() {
    Status test1 = Status::test1;
    Status test2 = Status::test2;
    if (test1==test2) {
        cout << "Enum same"<< endl;
    }
    if (static_cast<char>(test1) == static_cast<char>(test2)) {
        cout << "value same" << endl;
    }
}
```

Output,

```
Enum same
value same
```

So does this mean the comparision of `enum class` member is done by `static_cast`? Also will this comparison have any performance penality comparing to direct comparison from `char` to `char`?

Comment: Your enum value is 49 because that is the integer value of the char '1' so when you compare the enum values the compiler does an integer comparison - char is  just a really short integer.  See this: https://onlinegdb.com/rya4S9Krw

Answer (score 0):

C++ enums are only really a compiler time construct, at runtime they behave exactly the same as their underlying type. The compiler will replace both `Status::test1` and `Status::test2` with the constant `'1'` and casting that constant to a `char` will make no difference to the code generated.

Your code example generates the same code in both cases: https://godbolt.org/z/c8dM77